# Casting abstract class in JSP

Tags: java, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a class `Task`. This is the bean:

```
public class Task {

    @Autowired private User user;
    @Autowired private Machine machine;

    private String status;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }   

    public Machine getMachine() {
        return machine;
    }

    public void setMachine(Machine machine) {
        this.machine = machine;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
```

`Machine` is an abstract class with three sub classes: `Car`, `Truck`, and `Motorcycle`.

Then in my controller I am binding `Task` to a JSP:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute("task")Task task,
              BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

        System.out.println(task.toString());

        return "home";
    }
```

**My Problem:**

To make a new `Task` I need to know which type of `Machine` is being used. There is a menu on the form where the user decides which type of `Machine` it is. Is there a way to cast `Machine` to say, `Truck` inside the JSP and fill out the data?

Alternatively, can I bind multiple classes to the form? So I bind `Task`, `Truck`, `Car`, `Motorcycle`, and fill out all of them (leaving the non-selected `Machine`s null)? Then process the casting inside the post method?

Or have I really gone about this the wrong way and need to restructure how I'm doing things? If I can't work out the abstract class I am planning on just adding `Car`, `Truck`, `Motorcycle` to the Task bean and doing away with the abstract class all together.

Answer (score 0):

I would infact make a form-backing object that fits the form properties exactly. So personally, I would move away from the abstract class, at least in the binding layer.

This said, you can achieve close to what you want by custominzing an [InitBinder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder). You would resolve the concrete type based on the request parameter, e.g. `type`, here is an example

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String machineType = request.getParam("type");

    PropertyEditor machineEditor;
    if("car".equalsIgnoreCase(machineType )) {
        machineEditor = new Car();
    } else if("truck".equalsIgnoreCase(machineType ))
        machineEditor = new Truck();
    } else {
        machineEditor - new Motorcycle();
    }
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Machine.class, machineEditor);
}
```